Is it possible to export an interactive ggplot (ggplotly) to PowerPoint, whilst maintaining its interactivity?
Today I learned that it is possible to create an interactive ggplot using ggplotly.
I managed to export this plot using saveWidget(ggplotly(x), file = "myplot.html").
This works great. However, I now wonder whether you can export the plot to a PowerPoint or Word document whilst maintaining its interactivity. Does anyone know whether this is possible, and if so, how?
Thank you for your time.

Stefanie


I think if you want interactivity in a document you need to move to rmarkdown/quarto and for slides ioslides, see here and here

For interactive slides quarto revealjs is also great!
